# Man page commands not visible in iTerm2

Tags: macos, iterm2, manpage

I am using `iTerm2` (Build 1.0.0.20140112) on OS X 10.8.5. When I try to view the man pages I am not able to view the command when the man page opens up. I can read the rest contents for that command in the man page, however I am not able to see the command itself. All the occurrence of the command are invisible in the man page. Snapshot attached.[image]

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but on OSX you can type the name of a command in the terminal and right-click it and you get the option to view the manpage in a nice yellow pop-up window that you can scroll up and down and refer to while composing your command without needing a new window...

Comment: I use iterm2 extensively and was looking for what can fix my issue. However thank you for the new tip about seeing the manpage in the pop-up, I did not know that :)

Answer (score 5):

That's may because of the color!
the bold text will show up white, which is the same as your background color.
change your background color to gray,
or change the bold text color to other color.
(both in iTerm2's settings)

or use this command:
man xxx | cat

Comment: If font colors are not the issue, check the font contrast settings.

Comment: Bold font color was my issue. Thanks!